# Returning the value of a text field to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I know this is an extremely basic question but I'm very new to (non-HTML) programming and after taking most of the JS tracks on CodeAcademy, I'm still struggling to make any of the things I've learned actually work.

So I decided as a challenge to myself to design a simple JavaScript-based command line. Of course, the very first actual code that I write refuses to work, despite constant fiddling.

Here's the HTML (well, the relevant bit):

```
<input type="text" id="commandfield"></input>
<button type="button" onclick="enterCommand()">Enter</button>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
var field = document.getElementById("commandfield");

function enterCommand () {
    var input = field.value;
    alert(input);
}
```

...And no alert shows. I tested a plain string alert, and it worked fine, so I know the problem lies with the getting value of #commandfield. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is this code ran relative to the HTML?

Comment: alex makes a valid point, if you try to look for the element on the document before it is rendered then it will be undefined. You have to do that after the element has been rendered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the element inside the function:

```
function enterCommand () {
    var field = document.getElementById("commandfield");
    if (field) {
        var input = field.value;
        alert(input);
    }
}
```

This will select the element given the state of the DOM at the time the event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
function enterCommand () {
    var field = document.getElementById("commandfield");      
    var input = field.value;
    alert(input);
}
```

Try this,I think you put the script in head tag,not the bottom of the body tag.

So could not GET that Node

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, and this works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enterCommand () {
var field = document.getElementById("commandfield");
var input = field.value;
window.alert(input);
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="commandfield" id="commandfield">
<button type="button" onclick="enterCommand()">Enter</button>
```